# Classification of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_{xxxx}+4u_{xy}=\tan x$$
Is it linear? (I think it is linear)

And what is the order of the PDE? (it is $4$?)

And other question:
$$u_{xx}+4u_{xyy}=0$$
the order of the last PDE is $3$ (not $2$), right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PDE

$u_{xxxx}+4u_{xy}=\tan x$ has order $4$, but is not linear. If $u$ and $v$ are solutions and $w:=u+v$, then  $w_{xxxx}+4w_{xy}=2 \tan x \ne \tan x$.

Hence $w$ is not a solution.

The PDE

$u_{xx}+4u_{xyy}=0$ has order $3$.

Comment: Thank you. If the pde is $w_{xxxx}+4w_{xy}=2 \tan x$ , is it nonlinear again because of term $w_{xy}$, right?

Comment: $u_{xxxx}+4u{xy}=\tan(x)$ is LINEAR.